# Возможно ли в Spring с помощью EasyMock создать мок бина, который не указан в конфиге приложения?

Tags: java, spring

Spring 3.2

Проблема такая, нужно написать тест на уровень rest сервисов и замокать весь уровень менеджеров, иначе контекст просто не поднимется. Потому что spring  скажет что нет такого бина. 
То есть допустим в test-context.xml для каждого такого менеджера я должен объявить

```
<bean id="manager1" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock">
    constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Class" value="a.a.Manager1" />
</bean>
```

но проблема в том, что таких менеджеров около сотни и получается, я должен в ручную создать моки этих бинов.

я пока додумался создать MockFactory

```
public class EasyMockBeanFactory implements FactoryBean {

private Class type;

@Override
public Object getObject() throws Exception {
    return EasyMock.createNiceMock(type);
}

@Override
public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return type;
}

@Override
public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
}

public Class getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(Class type) {
    this.type = type;
}
}
```

которая создает мне мок класса, который я передам.

Так же удалось расширить DefaultListableBeanFactory

```
public class DefaultMockBeanFactory extends DefaultListableBeanFactory {

@Override
public BeanDefinition getBeanDefinition(String beanName) throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException {
    return super.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
}

@Override
protected <T> T doGetBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType, Object[] args, boolean typeCheckOnly) throws BeansException {
    if (super.containsBeanDefinition(name)) {
        return super.doGetBean(name, requiredType, args, typeCheckOnly);
    }
    logger.info("need mock: " + name);
    registerBeanDefinition(name, createDef(requiredType));
    return super.doGetBean(name, requiredType, args, typeCheckOnly);
}

private RootBeanDefinition createDef(Class type) {
    RootBeanDefinition rootBeanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(EasyMockBeanFactory.class);
    MutablePropertyValues propertyValues = new MutablePropertyValues();
    propertyValues.add("type", type);
    rootBeanDefinition.setPropertyValues(propertyValues);
    return rootBeanDefinition;
}
}
```

но проблема в том, что в этом методе Class requiredType всегда null, соответственно я не могу узнать тип данного класса, чтобы создать из него мок.

Имеется ли возможность в Spring указать, что если нет какого либо бина, то создать его с помощью MockFactory. Либо переопределить какой либо бин сканнер, который уже после генерации имени бина (который будет использоваться в качестве зависимости), будет сохранять имя кандидата на бин и его тип, чтобы потом использовать это в DefaultListableBeanFactory.

Вопрос конечно немного наркоманский. Может существую и другие пути для достижения данной цели.